# User profile pictures disappearing - OU migration in AD

Tags: user-profile, migration, ad

I'm no expert on the synchronisation of user profiles between AD and SP, so I'd be **hugely** grateful if somebody could clarify and expand on  the following - 
  User profile images for users are disappearing from my organisations SP farm. This only affects accounts that have migrated to a differing OU within AD (and in the same domain). 
  Could anyone explain why that occurs? Is it because SP treats each migrated profile as a new profile entirely and doesn't carry the picture across? or is it some reason entirely different?
 Going forward, all users within the organisation are being migrated OU's within AD. I am hoping there is a way this migration can be implemented without losing all the user profile pictures for the entire organisation. Again, any suggestions welcome?

Answer (score 0):

first, Make sure the Sync is configured to pickup the new OU.  You can then try and run this

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 -MySiteHostLocation <siteurl>
```